# Does LibSVM accept training files with floating-point numbers in the scientific format?

Tags: svm, libsvm

Does **LibSVM** accept floating-point numbers in the scientific format?

A feature with…

```
index: 4
value: 1.04515435733819E-05
```

…would look like this:

```
4:1.04515435733819E-05
```

I'm having a large training file which is full of floating-point values with their exponents ranging from `-06` to `+31`.

(Note: I'm concerned about the format of the feature value.
I know the format of the training file, i.e: `label index:value index:value ...`)

I'm using **Visual C++ 2010** and I'm writing the `value` to a file using the `String` and `StreamWriter` classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that **LibSVM** (**v3.16**) uses `stdlib`'s `double strtod(const char *, char **)` function to read the feature values it should accept **every notation that can be read by `strtod()`**.

(Btw, the same goes for the labels, which as can be seen in the snippet below, can be floating point numbers, too.)

The code in question can be found in `void read_problem(const char *filename)` from the `svm-train.c` file from **LibSVM**'s source code distribution.

Here it is in a stripped-down version of the relevant part of `read_problem(...)`:

```
label = strtok(*line," \t\n");
problem->y[i] = strtod(label,&endptr);                 // document label
while (1) {
    idx = strtok(NULL,":");
    val = strtok(NULL," \t");
    (*x_space)[j].index = (int)strtol(idx,&endptr,10); // feature index
    (*x_space)[j].value = strtod(val,&endptr);         // feature value
    ++j;
}
```

Comment: But, changing ...E-05 to ...E+05 will change the meaning of the data. And if I try to shift the complete data-set from negative exponents to positive ones, of course, I am prone to go out of bounds.